# Recurring payment gives an error

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox, easy-digital-downloads

I created a test business account on sandbox environment and used a wordpress plugin "Easy Digital Downloads" to deploy recurring payments or subscriptions, but when I click on purchase button, I get this error:

> This feature is only available to Business and Premier Accounts

My main account is Business account, and the testing account I use is also a business account. I tested it with a real account instead of using a sandbox account and it works fine.

What can be the cause of this issue and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the sandbox account. Kindly create a new sandbox business account with another email address at developer.paypal.com. [Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/) for more information. If you are still seeing the same error message with newly created sandbox account kindly connect with Paypal Support team at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com.